# XMLDocument -> Byte[] ... how to get back to XMLDocument?

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays, type-conversion, xmldocument

I have an XmlDocument and get the bytes of the object as follows:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("C:\\myxml.xml");

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocument.outerXml);
```

and data is stored in a database.

Now I am reading the byte[] data back out, and want to get back to the XmlDocument object.  How can I do this, as I cannot simply case the byte[] to an XmlDocument?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) method:

```
byte[] data = ... fetch from your db
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
// TODO: do something with the resulting XmlDocument
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's how to load the byte array into a `DataTable`:

```
byte[] data = ... fetch from your db
DataTable dt = ... fetch from somewhere or instantiate a new;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    dt.ReadXml(stream);
}
```

Comment: If I want to get this XML into a DataTable...it does not allow dataTable.ReadXml(xmlDoc), as it is expecting a stream or filename...how can I read this XML into a data table?

Comment: @John, I have updated my answer in order to illustrate this scenario.